# AppleScript - How to set variables for an undetermined number of list items?

Tags: applescript, automator, automation

I'm new to AppleScript. I'm trying to create a script which takes the list items from a previous Automator workflow action and convert them into variables.

There will be an undetermined number of list items (well, between 1 and 40 each run).

This works for a determined number of list items, let's say three.

```
on run {input, parameters}

    set value of variable "F1" of front workflow to item 1 of input
    set value of variable "F2" of front workflow to item 2 of input
    set value of variable "F3" of front workflow to item 3 of input

    return input
end run
```

But if there are only two list items generated from the previous workflow action, we run into problems.

So, I updated the script using `if` to try to get around this issue.

```
on run {input, parameters}

    if item 1 exists then
        set value of variable "F1" of front workflow to item 1 of input
    end if
    if item 2 exists then
        set value of variable "F2" of front workflow to item 2 of input
    end if
    if item 3 exists then
        set value of variable "F3" of front workflow to item 3 of input
    end if

    return input
end run
```

When I run this, only the first variable `F1` populates. The others are left blank/do not populate. I'm not sure how to move forward with this?

Can anyone tell me if I'm on the right track, or if there's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

*Variable* declaration must be made before *run* time. The following *example* **AppleScript** *code*, run in **Script Editor**, is to demonstrate a way of doing it:

```
set input to {"one", "two", "three"}

set F1 to missing value
set F2 to missing value
set F3 to missing value
set F4 to missing value

try
    if item 1 of input is not missing value then
        set F1 to item 1 of input
        log "F1 is: " & F1
    end if
    if item 2 of input is not missing value then
        set F2 to item 2 of input
        log "F2 is: " & F2
    end if
    if item 3 of input is not missing value then
        set F3 to item 3 of input
        log "F3 is: " & F3
    end if
    if item 4 of input is not missing value then
        set F4 to item 4 of input
        log "F4 is: " & F4
    end if
end try

log "F4 is still: " & F4
```

The log result is:

```
(*F1 is: one*)
(*F2 is: two*)
(*F3 is: three*)
(*F4 is still: missing value*)
```

Obviously the `log` *command* is being used to show that the *variables* were assigned a new *value*, except the last one because the `input list` only had three *items* in it. You'll need to built this out for however many *variables* could be needed, as you can't add them after execution of the *code* has started. You mentioned "between 1 and 40 each run" in your OP.

You'd remove the `log` *commands* for the real *code*  within each of the `if` *statement* blocks, besides the *variable* assignments, as appropriate at that point in the execution of the *code*, if any.

Note that by wrapping the *code* of the group of `if` *statement* blocks, that sets the new *value* of the *variables* based on the *value* of the `list item`, in a `try` *statement* when there are less `items` in the `input list`, it doesn't throw an *error* that would halt execution of the *code*, and continues with the remaining *code*.

The *value* of the *variable* is initially being assigned `missing value`, however `""` (double-quotes) can be used instead as well. I like to use `missing value` at times as it can be easier to read the *code*.

**NOTE:** The *example* **AppleScript** *code* above it just that, and is coded as is to demonstrate a way of assigning the *variables* a *value* from a *list*. Which is what `input` is in the context of e.g. `on run {input, parameters}` of a **Run AppleScript** *action* in an **Automator** *workflow*. Depending on what the source of the `input` is and what will be done with it, you may need to add e.g. `as string` or `as text` or other *coercion* as appropriate as/if applicable, in this case after `item n of input`, e.g. `set F1 to item 1 of input as string`.